# Quando devo utilizar "return" ou "print" em uma função?

Tags: python

Podem exemplificar alguma situação que pode ser exercida por um comando mas não em outro? Porque aqui deu a mesma coisa nos dois comandos.

Usando `print`:

```
>>> def media(x1, x2):
...     print((x1+x2)/2)
>>> x = media(1, 3)
2
```

Usando `return`:

```
>>> def medya(y1, y2):
...     return ((y1+y2)/2)
>>> y = medya(1, 3)
>>> y
2
```

Comment: Não é a mesma coisa. Tente verificar o valor de `x` para você ver.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss isso acabou me ocasionando mais uma dúvida. O que obtive foi o seguinte:

>>> print(x)
None
>>> print(y)
5.0

mas se x é resultado da função media, pq temos que 

print(x) retorna NONE?

Answer (score 5):

Não é a mesma coisa. No seu exemplo até parece ser, mas é porque não é um bom exemplo.

Se você averiguar um pouco mais a fundo, verá que quando usado `print`, embora o valor correto seja exibido, o valor de `x` que **recebe o retorno** da função será nulo, `None`.

```
>>> def media(a, b):
...     print((a+b)/2)
>>> x = media(1, 3)
2
>>> print(x)
None
```

Ou seja, ao utilizar o `print` o resultado é enviado ao *buffer* de saída e depois descartado. O valor `x`, que iria receber o resultado, recebe um valor nulo, pois a função não tem retorno.

Diferente se você utilizar o `return`, pois o valor será retornado pela função e atribuído em `x`:

```
>>> def media(a, b):
...     return (a+b)/2
>>> x = media(1, 3)
>>> print(x)
2
```

Perceba que mesmo chamando a função, a saída não é exibida até ser executado o `print(x)`, isso porque a função envia o retorno para `x` e não mais para o *buffer* de saída.

Imagine que você precisa somar 5 na média entre 1 e 3. Usando `print` você não conseguirá fazer `x+5`, pois `x` é nulo, uma vez que a função não teve retorno - e não é possível somar 5 em nulo. Já utilizando o `return`, o resultado 2 será *armazenado* em `x` e, assim, será possível somar 5.

De forma ideal, uma função não deve utilizar `print`, a menos que essa seja explicitamente seu objetivo: exibir os dados. Uma função que **calcula** a média não deveria ter a responsabilidade de **exibir** a média. Isso quebra o princípio de responsabilidade única e deixa seu código pouco reutilizável.

Quando você utiliza o `return`, você terá acesso direto e poder de manipular o retorno da função, o que gera um código muito mais versátil e maleável para você.

Imagine o seguinte problema:

- Some a média entre 1 e 3 com a média entre 7 e 9.

Usando o `print`, o resultado a primeira média, 2, será exibido na tela, bem como o resultado da segunda média, 8. Precisará alguém fazer manualmente a soma de 2 e 8 para obter o resultado 10.

Quando você usa o `return`, você consegue acessar os resultados dentro do programa ainda, podendo fazer:

```
>>> x = media(1, 3)
>>> y = media(7, 9)
>>> x+y
10
```

Você não precisa saber quais são os resultados parciais para obter o total; se por acaso precisar mudar `media(7, 9)` para `media(7, 11)`, o resultado `x+y` automaticamente passará a ser 11.

Answer (score 1):

Optei por lhe responder da maneira mais simples possível ignorando todas as formalidades:

Apesar de parecerem iguais, elas são totalmente diferentes e são utilizadas em contextos completamente diferentes.

A função `print` é usada para imprimir uma dada informação no console (terminal) onde estiver programando. Observe: **print** significa **impressão** em inglês.

Quanto a função `return`, retorna alguma informação de "dentro" de uma função qualquer. Observe: **return** significa **retornar** em inglês

Essa coincidência acontece no python, mas em java por exemplo você não conseguiria ver a impressão de um return como foi feito sem uma função "print".

Espero que tenha entendido!

Answer (score 1):

A sua confusão vem do fato do python, **no prompt de comando (REPL) `>>>`**, imprimir automaticamente o valor retornado.

Isso não ocorre normalmente, só quando está executando comandos no prompt imediato do python - é uma questão de *conveniência* - para facilitar o uso do interpretador imediato de comandos, tem um `print()` embutido que imprime o valor de retorno.

Em um programa verdadeiro, onde você escreve o código em um arquivo e comanda a execução do mesmo, somente o `print()` gera saída na tela. O `return` não vai gerar saída nenhuma neste caso.